# Cocoa's WebView does not load a URL upon loading the app

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I'm making a simple app, to load up a single URL, I have the following code

webberAppDelegate.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
@interface webberAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    NSWindow *window;
    WebView *webber;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (assign) IBOutlet WebView *webber;
@end
```

webberAppDelegate.m

```
#import "webberAppDelegate.h"

@implementation webberAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize webber;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSString *urlString = @"http://www.apple.com";
    // Insert code here to initialize your application 
    [[webber mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]];
}

@end
```

What do I have to do in Interface builder? I've added the Web View, do I need to link it in any way?

Thing is I added simple text field(and linked it to the web view) and it loads the URL just fine when I enter it there, however it doesn't with this code, any ideas?

Comment: [Automatic Reference Counting](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html), which is enabled by default for all new projects since Xcode 4.2. If you are using it, you should change that property declaration to `@property (strong) IBOutlet WebView *webber;` or your `WebView` instance might be deallocated.

Comment: You might also want to ensure that your web view is hooked up in your XIB.

Comment: When you say hooked up, what do you mean? It's there, what should I hook it up to in the xib?

Comment: @Rob Keniger I'm running 3.2.2 so I doubt thats the case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your XIB file, you should have an App Delegate object (and some other things).

[image: Objects]

Right-clicking it should bring up a HUD list, where you'll see each of your outlets (and, again, some other things).Find the `webber` outlet, and click the circle to its right. Then drag to your `WebView`.

[image: Linking]

What you've just done is linked your properties to your XIB objects. Skip this step, and your App Delegate won't know what `webber` is referring to.

Also, note that in order to populate that HUD list, your properties need to be specifically tagged with `IBOutlet`.

Comment: life saver for new devs